# hacer una función booleana que diga si las listas son iguales

Tags: c++, array, booleano

Soy nueva en programación y no entiendo donde he fallado. Mi función no quiere entrar al bucle.

```
bool iguales(int *p1, unsigned int tam1, int *p2, unsigned int tam2){
    
    
    if(tam1 != tam2){ 
        cout<<"Las listas no son iguales\n"; //hacemos la primera prueba. Si los tamanyos son diferentes adelante no entra al bucle porque no es necesario
        return false;
    }
    
    
    
    else {
        tam2 = tam1;
        bool igual = false;
        for(int i=tam1-1; i>-1; i--){
           if(p1[i]==p2[i]){
               igual=true;
               return true;
          //     break;
           }
           cout<<"Las listas no son iguales\n";
            igual=false;
           return false;
         //   break;
       }
        
        if(igual==true){
            cout<<"Las listas son iguales\n";
        } else{
            cout<<"Las listas son diferentes\n";
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Lo que no quiere funcionar es comprobar cada numero de dos listas con cada uno. Comprueba solo primer numero y para, diciendo que las listas son iguales. Si por ejemplo le envío 2 listas: {1,2,3,4} y {1,7,3,9}, me dice que son iguales porque empiezan con el mismo numero. Alguien puede explicarme por favor que tengo mal? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int contIguales = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
{
   if(p1[i] == p2[i]
   {
      contIguales++;
   } 
}

return contIguales == tam;
```

Primero recorremos el array desde la primera posición hasta la última y vamos comparando los dos arreglos por cada posición del mismo, de ser iguales, incrementamos la **variable contIguales**, después de salir del ciclo, preguntamos si el tamaño del arreglo es igual a **contIguales** de ser cierto quiere decir que los dos arreglos son iguales, de ser falso quiere decir que no son iguales.

Otra cosa katia, dentro de esta función no debes imprimir, por lo que todos tu **cout** sobran, esta función solo es responsable de verificar si las lista son iguales o no.

Ej. de llamada:

```
bool sonIguales = iguales(lista1, tam1, lista2, tam2);
```

y entonces aquí es donde preguntarías para saber si son iguales o no:

```
if(sonIguales)
{
   //Imprime son iguales
} 
else
{
   //Imprime no son iguales
}
```

Comment: Me sigue no saliendo
   `else {

        int contIguales=0;

        bool igual = false;
        for(int i=0; i>tam1; i++){
           if(p1[i]==p2[i]){
               contIguales++;
               cout<<"Las listas son igualesP\n";
//               igual=true;
//               return true;
//               break;
               
           }`

Comment: @KatiaSkripnikova dame un tiempo y en un rato te ayudo

Comment: @KatiaSkripnikova, no estas haciendo lo que te puse, fijate bien, haciendo lo que te propongo ya no te hace falta la variable igual, ademas no tienes que imprimir dentro de la funcion esto va afuera

Comment: @KatiaSkripnikova, revisa lo nuevo que te puse

Answer (score 0):

Como alternativa al código propuesto por Japv, puedes verificar si un arreglo es igual a otro haciendo lo contrario: asegurarte de que no haya un elemento diferente.

Si no hay ningún elemento diferente, significa que ambos arreglos son iguales.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
   if (p1[i] != p2[i])
       return false;

return true;
```