# Java.- Secuencias Iguales

Tags: java, array

Tengo problemas para este ejercicio que me esta confundiendo y quiero saber cual es la forma de resolverlo
Lo que entendi fue que hiciera 2 arreglos y comparar si son iguales o diferentes

El ejercicio dice:

> Escribe un programa que determine si dos secuencias de  enteros son iguales.
>
> **Entrada:** Un entero  seguido de los  enteros de la primera secuencia y
> posteriormente los  enteros de la segunda secuencia.

Intente hacer el codigo pero soy muy malo para esto:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                          new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());

   int n = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    int [] numeros=new int[n];
    st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
    int [] numeros2=new int[n];

for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
  numeros[i]=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
numeros2[j]=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
if(numeros[i]==numeros[j]){
  System.out.println("1");
}else{
  System.out.println("0");
}
}
}
     }
}
```

Comment: Para comparar si dos array son iguales se usa un único bucle. {1, 2, 3} y {1, 2, 4} serán iguales si la condición `if(array1[i] != array2[i])` jamás se cumple.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417044/hacer-una-funci%c3%b3n-booleana-que-diga-si-las-listas-son-iguales/417062#417062, entra aquí

Comment: @TheBiggerSensei, agradecería que me dijeras si te fue de utilidad el vínculo que te di